# Cannot setup the smtp for mail sending

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I have add on the docker-composer.yml a new .py file for the email_settings (saved on the tcms_settings_dir)  and restarted docker container to refresh the settings and get the new file.
The email_config file is the following:

```
import os
import pathlib
import tempfile
from importlib import import_module

import pkg_resources
from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

import tcms

SERVER_EMAIL = DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'my@emailcom'
# additional Kiwi TCMS setting
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = '[Kiwi-TCMS] '

EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.my_server.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587 
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'admin@email.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my_pass'

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Then I try with:
sudo docker exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py sendtestemail my_email@email.com

and I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Kiwi/manage.py", line 12, in <module> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

  File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line utility.execute()

  File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)

  File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)

  File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 460, in execute output = self.handle(*args, **options)

  File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/sendtestemail.py", line 35, in handle
    send_mail(File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 87, in send_mail return mail.send()

  File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 298, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])

  File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 124, in send_messages new_conn_created = self.open()

  File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 80, in open self.connection = self.connection_class(File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 253, in __init__ (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 337, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 308, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
    raise err

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)

OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

I have checked that the computer hosting the docker container can connect with the smtp server (pinged) and the smtp settings are correct, because they are currently in use on a laravel project.
I don't know if I have to open ports on the docker container in order to communicate with the smtp server.

Can you please assist on what could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your configuration is correct this error is a generic network error. There are so many things that can go wrong on the network layer itself.

- Did you try to verify that your settings are indeed correct?
- Did you verify network connectivity between the container and the SMTP server ?  For example using some command line tools ?
- Did you inspect firewall and actual SMTP configuration for obvious things like allowing/blocking particular ports and addresses ?

**Action required:** provide all of the above information in the original question if you want to make any progress here.

**Update:** the provided details still don't help because this error is just too generic to be able to understand what's happening. It is some sort of a networking issue but without access to the system running the container (and exposing the email credentials) we can't debug anything.

Comment: I have added the requested details on my post.

Comment: pinging the SMTP server from the Kiwi TCMS container doesn't mean that this email server will accept incoming connections on 587 from the container's IP address. Ping uses port 53 IIRC.  The Laravel reference means settings values are probaly correct but doesn't help in establishing information about your networking setup.